# Angular bubble events from transcluded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a tag selection directive that has multiple tags in it, I'd like to know how I bubble the `remove` event to the parent directive.

My code:

```
app.controller('MainController', function( $scope ) {
  $scope.tags = [
    'Lorem Ipsum',
    'Dolor Sit'
  ];
});

app.directive('tagsSelect', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'tags': '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'src/templates/tags-select.html',
    transclude: true
  };
});

app.directive('tag', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'name': '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'src/templates/tag.html',
    link: function( scope, element, atrrs ) {
      scope.remove = function( tag ) {
        // TODO: Remove tag from parent & scope...
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**tags-select.html**

```
<tag ng-repeat="tag in tags" name="tag"></tag>
```

**tag.html**

```
{{name}} <span class="remove-tag" ng-click="remove(tag)">X</span>
```

**index.html**

```
<tags-select tags="tags"></tags-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require the controller of your `tagsSelect` directive in your `tag` directive:

```
app.directive('tagsSelect', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'tags': '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'src/templates/tags-select.html',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
        // *** Put the methods on 'this' not '$scope' ***
        this.removeTag = function(tag) {
            $scope.tags.splice($scope.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
        };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('tag', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      'name': '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'src/templates/tag.html',
    require: '^tagsSelect',
    link: function( scope, element, atrrs, tagsSelectCtrl ) {
      scope.remove = function( tag ) {
          tagsSelectCtrl.removeTag(tag);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

As you can see, the `tagsSelect` directive now has a controller (allowing it to be required by another directive), and in this controller you are exposing the `removeTag()` method.

Now in the `tag` directive, you are requiring the `tagsSelect` controller which is passed as a fourth parameter to your link function. You will now be able to communicate with the parent controller.

Comment: I'm getting an `undefined is not a function` error on the `tagsSelectCtrl.removeTag` call, could you try to put up a working version on plnkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: @JonKoops Sorry my bad, you need to put the `removeTag()` method on `this` not `$scope` in the controller of the `tagsSelect` directive... I guess I should've tested this! That should do it... I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Angular's Directives are still a big black box to me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transclude `tagsSelect` directive in this case. See if this solution works for you:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oKYF2PcxmvpVLoRLRAuq?p=preview).